# Pattern matching in definition of fromJust

Tags: performance, haskell, pattern-matching

The function `fromJust` in `Data.Maybe` is defined in this way:

```
fromJust          :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust Nothing  = error "Maybe.fromJust: Nothing"
fromJust (Just x) = x
```

According to my understanding of pattern matching (matching proceeds from top to bottom) I would change the order of the two definitions. Since usually the Nothing-part doesn't match in a it-is-sure-a-Just situation, but it is always checked before the second definition is reached.

Can you please clarify my error in reasoning? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Example:
Suppose I have a file with a million numbers of type `Int` per line and y need this numbers (as `Int`, not `String`) in my program for other stuff.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L

readInt = fst . fromJust . L.readInt
-- more stuff
```

With the above definition of `fromJust` I would need more time to read the numbers, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this question is about performance.  While *semantically* pattern matching is tested top-to-bottom, most Haskell compilers will optimize matching on an ADT's constructors to the equivalent of a C `switch` statement.

You can think of the data representation for an ADT has a "tag" which says which constructor it was made with, together with a pointer for each argument.  So for example, `Nothing` might be represented as `0 (null)` and `Just 42` represented as `1 (pointer to 42)`.

Then in a function like this:

```
squash :: Maybe (Maybe Int) -> Int
squash (Just Nothing) = 0
squash Nothing = 0
squash (Just (Just x)) = x
```

The compiler would set up a decision tree:

```
squash x = 
   check tag of x:
       0 -> 0
       1 y -> check tag of y:
           0 -> 0
           1 z -> z
```

Where each tag is computed by a jump table or something, so it is no more expensive to check against `0` as `1`.  Note that this same decision tree would be made no matter what the original order of the patterns in our definition.

However, when using guards instead of matching on  a constructor, the patterns are most likely checked from top to bottom (the compiler would have to be *very* smart to optimize that).  So if we wrote `fromJust` in this arcane way:

```
fromJust x
    | isNothing x = error "fromJust: Nothing"
    | isJust x = case x of { Just y -> y }
```

Then this would probably check for each constructor in turn, and we could optimize by switching the order of the cases.  Fortunately, writing in a way that this matters is cumbersome :-).

Answer (score 6):

There are two important things to realize here: First, the Haskell compiler is fully aware that any value can only either be `Nothing` or `Just x`. Therefore it will only ever test for one of them. Second, GHC uses pointer tagging that allows it to distinguish between pointers pointing at various constructors very fast ([details](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/HaskellExecution/PointerTagging)).

As a result, GHC generates quite nice code for the pattern match. Here's what the `fromJust` return code looks like, taken directly from the assembly dump:

```
        andq $7,%rax
        cmpq $2,%rax
        jae .LcO4
```

This takes the return value, then extracts the tag using a bit mask operation (7 = 111 in binary). If this tag is 2, then the code knows that it points to a `Just x` constructor. Therefore it jumps to the appropriate code. Otherwise, it just continues to the code dealing with `Nothing`.

I *think* this could even be optimized further using the knowledge that there is only ever one `Nothing` closure in the program. Therefore you could replace that with a single address comparison, saving the bit-masking operations and even a register in the actual code. Not sure why GHC doesn't do this.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to dive into the low level details, but it's not my strong suit

Answer (score 0):

Something that matches `Nothing` cannot possible match `Just`. So both orders work.

If you pass `Just 5` through `fromJust`, `Just 5` does not match `Nothing`. But `Just 5` does match `Just x`.

It would work exactly the same either way. Things only start to get sticky when a function doesn't pattern match on one of the arguments.

Comment: With more complicated data structures, does pattern matching affect laziness?  e.g. If I want to see if an element has 1,2 or 3 elements and I give something with more, presumably it evaluates at least the first three items of the list?

Comment: Jeff Foster, At least with a simple case like `myhead (x:y:zs) = x` ; `myhead (x:zs) = x` ; `myhead _ = error "Headless!"`, it doesn't force the second element, if there is one. See http://codepad.org/v09GzUnG

Comment: @applicative it actually does force additional list item unnecessarily: http://codepad.org/XG87mdZR

Comment: The question is about performance, not about correctness. Thus -1.

Comment: Rotsor: it forces the list *spine* that far. Not the element.

Comment: @Rotsor the question was edited after I posted my answer. I love it when people -1 because I didn't see an edit... I _did_ answer the original question (which was honestly pretty unclear), so your -1 is unfounded.

Comment: @mathepic The question was always about performance if read carefully. However, this has not much to do with the current "This answer is not useful" status.

Comment: @Edward, "spine"! That's the word I was looking for! :) Anyway, my point is that strictness *does* depend on the order of those patterns.

Comment: @Rotsor I'm not going to delete an answer because the question had nothing to with performance in the original form when I answered.

Comment: @mathepic, to me, a -1 isn't so much a request to delete as a "move this answer lower on the page because it isn't as useful as others".  Also perhaps a hint to read questions a bit more deeply...

Comment: @luqui The original question (look it up please) had nothing to do with performance.

Comment: @mathepic, try not to take downvotes personally.  +2/-2 still gives you +16 reputation.  We're just trying to create a page that addresses what the OP wanted, even if he didn't state it very clearly the first time.  I apologize if I sounded condescending with my "hint", I didn't mean it that way.